# Python, how to setup hooks for tracing I/O Events

Tags: python, events, io, hook, centos

My app downloads files, creates files as final/intermediate data. I would like to setup a hook (outside the app), to alert/log whenever my app does any I/O events - like writing a file, deleting a file, downloading a file from the file server. I use the urllib to retrieve fits files from the data servers.

Answer (score 2):

If you know where the file will be downloaded to, one solution could be to use inotify.  In particular, [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify) seems interesting.  I don't know if CentOS has a recent enough version of the Linux kernel for this to work though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of your process file operations, you can use [FileMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) or [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from SysInternals.

**Edit:** for Linux, you can use *strace*.

Comment: I guess this is for windows based machines!

Comment: For Linux, you have *strace*.

Comment: my challenge is how to filter out the information i need from the output of strace.

Comment: Then I guess you could start by reading *starce* source code and implement filtering above it.